Choosing a transition metal catalyst instead of iron catalyst to investigate the degradation of methyl orange?
I was working on a dye degradation project for methyl orange (MO), using Fenton's Reaction. I plan on keeping a constant pH of 2. Normally, the reaction is done with an Iron catalyst, but at lower pH levels, using an iron-based catalyst has significant drawbacks (sludge formation, etc.) and a low efficiency.
It is advised that other transition metals with at least two oxidation states such as Cu, Ru, Mn, Ag, and Co, can catalyze the formation of hydroxyl radicals from H2O2. However, how do I go about choosing the transition metal catalyst for my project. Which transition metal would be the most suitable and why?(I do not mind investigating multiple catalysts (with different oxidation states))
I saw a few studies use CuO and Cu-based nanoparticles, but are there any alternatives to this? Furthermore, are there any other transition metals that should be avoided as catalysts for reasons similar to that of iron at acidic pH levels?

According to Ref.1:

In recent research, nickel oxide nanoparticles have drawn a greater interest, because of its unique properties. It belongs to a wide band gap $(3.6–\pu{4.0 eV})$ p-type semiconductor and is chemically stable with high electro-optical efficiency. Nickel oxide nanoparticles are widely applied in numerous fields as adsorbents, solar and fuel cells, catalytic agents, gas sensors, magnetic and antibacterial materials (references sited).

The abstract of the paper states:
The $\mathrm{pH}$ solution plays an important role in the photocatalytric reaction. An amount of $\pu{0.75 g/L}$ of $\ce{EGNiO}$ catalyst was found to provide the optimum dosage for 10 mg/L methyl orange (MO) dye resulting in a nearly complete degradation which amounted 96.8% within $\pu{1.5 h}$ of contact time. The catalyst showed good performance in $\mathrm{pH \ 3}$ (acidic medium) due to the influence of electrostatic attractions and also surface charge properties. The presence of highly excess of hydroxyl radicals formation during the photoreaction is suggested to demolished the MO molecules as there is no deposition of MO dye occurred on the surface of catalyst as been observed. The excellence photoresponse under visible light regions give advantage for the photocatalytic reaction which is cost effective, practicable, and more eco-friendliness.
$\ce{EGNiO}$ is guar gum (GG) mediated $\ce{NiO}$ nanoparticle catalyst (vide infra for synthesis). The authors have investigated the influence of $\mathrm{pH}$ on the photocatalytic degradation of methyl orange using this nickel catalyst. The results are as follows:

The degradation percentage was calculated using the following Equation $(1)$ at constant temperature:
$$degradation \ percentage\% = \frac{(C_0 - C_t)}{C_0} \times 100 \tag1$$
where $C_0$ and $C_t$ are the initial concentration of dye and the concentration at time $t$, respectively.
For the study, $C_\ce{EGNiO} = \pu{0.75 g/L}$, $C_\mathrm{MO} = \pu{10 mg/L}$, and $t = \pu{1.5 h}$ at $T = \pu{303 K}$. Degradation is studied spectrophotometrically at $\lambda = \pu{450 nm}$.
General synthetic procedure for $\ce{GNiO}$ nanoparticulate (Ref.2): An aqueous solution of guar gum ($\pu{15 mL}$ of 1% (w/v)) was added to $\pu{10 mL}$ $\ce{NiSO4·6H2O}$ solution (of a known concentration ranging from $\pu{0.05 M}$ to $\pu{0.15 M}$) and the mixture was stirred until a green transparent solution was obtained. $\ce{NaOH}$ $(\pu{0.1 M})$ solution was slowly added (drop wise until $\mathrm{pH \ 11}$ was obtained) to this mixture to precipitate the nickel hydroxide which was separated by centrifugation, washed well with water, and dried. Finally it was dried at $\pu{60 ^\circ C}$ and calcined in an electric muffle furnace at $\pu{500 ^\circ C}$ (in air) for $\pu{1 h}$ to obtain particular $\ce{GNiO}$ sample. You may prepare different $\ce{GNiO}$ samples, which can be obtained by varying the molar concentration of $\ce{NiSO4·6H2O}$ during the synthesis, while concentration of guar gum and $\ce{NaOH}$ solutions were kept fixed at 1% (w/v) and $\pu{0.1 M}$, respectively.

References:

Muhammad Farhan Hanafi and Norzahir Sapawe, "Influence of pH on the photocatalytic degradation of methyl orange using nickel catalyst," Materials Today: Proceedings 2020, 31(1), 339-341 (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.matpr.2020.06.094).
Kirti Baranwal, Lalit Mohon Dwivedi, Shehala, and Vandana Singh, "Guar gum mediated synthesis of $\ce{NiO}$ nanoparticles: An efficient catalyst for reduction of nitroarenes with sodium borohydride," International Journal of Biological Macromolecules 2018, 120(B), 2431-2441 (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijbiomac.2018.09.013).


Iron will not form sludges at low pH.

However, how do I go about choosing the transition metal catalyst for
my project. Which transition metal would be the most suitable and why?

If you are thinking in terms of "green chemistry", iron is still the greenest catalyst in Fenton's system. You need to think in terms of post-process waste treatment and disposal as well. Nickel ion is a carcinogen, copper ion is also toxic most living things at high conc., silver and cobalt are expensive. Iron is dirt cheap and it is everywhere, even in our blood. Perhaps

"Sludge formation with high iron contents, the deactivation of iron because of complex formation and a specific pH range (2.0–4.0) dependency are considered as the significant shortcomings of the homogeneous process. All these drawbacks can be conquered by the functionalization of the heterogeneous catalytic approach [88,89]. In heterogeneous catalysis, iron is sustained within the catalytic structure and can efficiently stimulate the degradation of recalcitrant materials without the formation of ferric hydroxide sludge. " Source: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6603921/

Ronith, the authors are making a sweeping statement. All metals can potentially form a sludge if the pH is elevated to neutralization.
